# OpenCV: fs.open fails

Tags: c++, xml, opencv

I want to read from an .xml file, but this line

```
fs.open("test.xml", FileStorage::READ);
```

fails with cv::Exception.

\opencv_source\opencv-3.4.1\modules\core\src\persistence_c.cpp:384: error: (-49) Input file is empty in function cvOpenFileStorage\n" ...} ...}    const cv::Exception &

I'm using Win7, OpenCV 3.4.1, c++, VisualStudio 2015. It's my fist time using .xml files and I'm new to opencv.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Perhaps share the exception?

Comment: sorry - I forgot: \opencv_source\\opencv-3.4.1\\modules\\core\\src\\persistence_c.cpp:384: error: (-49) Input file is empty in function cvOpenFileStorage\n" ...} ...} const cv::Exception &

Comment: xml isn't empty ....

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/file_input_output_with_xml_yml/file_input_output_with_xml_yml.html

Comment: @macroland that's where the line is from

Answer (score 3):

If you have downloaded the XML file using "save link as..." from chrome, then it might cause the problem. Open the file and check it once if it looks the same as in the repository.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I had similar problem downloading XML file using "wget" command.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your program is unable to find the file specified. Is the file you are trying to open in the same directory as your excecutable? Perhaps try to use an absolute path.

Comment: it is in the same directory - works with absolute path... but yet it can't be opend -> if (!fs.isOpened()) says it. Is there a problem with the xml or encoder possible?

Answer (score 0):

It requires absolute path of the file to be read. I had the same issue. Giving absolute path solved my problem.